# How to draw border around Canvas in SWT

Tags: java, canvas, swt

Is it possible to have a Canvas with a border around it?  Passing `SWT.BORDER_SOLID` to the Canvas constructor does nothing:

```
imageCanvas = new Canvas(top, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED | SWT.BORDER_SOLID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SWT.BORDER` will do the trick.

The Javadoc of `SWT.BORDER_SOLID` states that it's:

> Used By: `TextStyle`